# Found and replace by Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I have this code:

```
<div>{phrase var="web_user" {0}="Try } Symbole" {1}="\"No\""}</div><div>{phrase var="web_admin" {0}="another" {1}="Is not any1."}</div>
```

I want replace `{phrase}` with result of function `translate`. The call of `translate` function need to be with `{\d}` parameters.
For example the code:

```
echo '<div>{phrase var="web_user" {0}="Try } Symbole" {1}="\"No\""}</div>';
```

should be:

```
echo '<div>'.translate("web_user", [0 => "Try } Symbole", 1=>"\"No\""]).'</div>';
```

I tryed to use `preg_replace_callback` without success.

My code:

```
$code = preg_replace_callback(
'/\{phrase\s+(.*)\}/iU',
function($phrase_data) {
    preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\\s*=\s*"([^\"])"/iU',$phrase_data[0], $parameters);
    call_user_func_array('translate', $parameters);
},
$code
);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show your PHP code?

Comment: @PEMapModder added :)

Comment: Your closure didn't return any values...

Comment: The `$parameters` is empty `Array()`.

Comment: I am saying that your anonymous function, the second parameter to the `preg_replace_callback`, does not return any values, which is unreasonable.